# Upgrade Extjs 3.3 to latest version

Tags: php, extjs

I'm using `Extjs 3.3.0` in my current project with `PHP` (custom framework).

I've found many helpful and usable features in the latest version of `Extjs`, that I'm looking for in my project. Can anybody suggest me some steps regarding how to upgrade the older version of `Extjs` that I’m currently using in my project to the latest one.

Answer (score 1):

I think the specific steps involved will depend on the size and scope of your project. The folks at Sencha have tried to lower the migration barriers by offering a migration pack to get your planning started.

[Ext JS 3 to 4 Migration](http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-3-to-4-migration/)

[Sencha Migration Screencasts](http://vimeo.com/23027769)

Also, a developer by the name of Steven Schwenke blogged about his experience migrating an application from 3 to 4:
[migrating from extjs 3 to extjs 4](http://stevenschwenke.de/migratingFromExtJS3ToExtJS4)

Hope that helps!

Comment: If that doesn't help, I can provide a personal contact to someone who migrated our ExtJS application with me. That migration was the foundation of the mentioned article.